# multiple calculations across tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the total cost of all the invoices for a customer.  Ideally the end format will be two columns [customer name] and [total of invoices].  I have broken it down into the parts so far so I can check and better understand the process of joining the tables and have done a calculation to get the total of items on each invoice but now I am stuck.

As you can see from my [screenshot](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxJ9hgcQ1wJGZXJITEtQS0JYVUE/edit?usp=sharing) ( Had to link to my google docs as I couldn't post the image up here - sorry) I am getting the company name listed multiple times. Once for each item and also for each invoice number and then item.  How can I change my query to show the customer name only once with the corresponding totals of all the invoices combined?

I have lines 3 and 4 as comments of what I think is next so I can work this in steps before fine tuning the query to my desired output.

Thanks

Comment: Please copy your code directly into the question as text using code tags, rather than giving a screenshot.  That way anyone who wants to help you can copy and paste to start with your query and modify it.  And please describe the table structures and put sample data into the question.

Comment: If Company Name is unique, do group by Company Name and sum of Invoices..

Comment: Thanks Dan I will do that in the future. Just realised how much harder I made it for everyone.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Customer.CustName, Sum(InvoiceItem.Quantity*Item.ItemPrice) As TotalValue
  From Customer
       Inner Join Invoice On Customer.CustABN = Invoice.CustABN
       Inner Join InvoiceItem On Invoice.InvoiceNo = InvoiceItem.InvoiceNo
       Inner Join Item On InvoiceItem.ItemNo = Item.ItemNo
 Group By Customer.CustName
```

Comment: Congratulations @Ciarán on achieving a rep of 1000.  Since it was my upvote that put you there, you owe me a beer.

Comment: <blush> thank you. What continent are you on?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  Sorry I didn't post my code :/ (n00b mistake) I realise that my aliases were really confusing. Your query is perfect.  Now to research more on joins so I can better understand them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work using `SUM` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT CustomerName, SUM(itemPrice * qty) InvoiceTotal
FROM YourTables With Your Joins
GROUP BY CustomerName
```

If you posted your entire query above, I could copy and paste into the example.  But this should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

grouping could help, also you need to check if your dbms allows grouping without using agregate functions (some DBMS do not allw it, and return misleading results).
multiple companies is because of the relation company-invoice-product i guess.